# How to visualize these numbers that are not appearing. (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an practice exercise for my Introduction to Programming class I have a doubt on (the code will be on here). The task is pretty simple, just merging two arrays and sorting them in ascending order. Now, I have everything down, but when I run the code, two of the numbers are not visible (the last two). The code for the complete program is down below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mergeSortedArrays(const int array1[], int size1, const int array2[], int size2, int result[])
{
    int tmp;
    bool swap;
    int sizefull = size1 + size2;
    int loops = 0;
    while (loops < size1)
    {
        result[loops] = array1[loops];
        loops++;
    }
    while (loops < sizefull)
    {
        result[loops] = array2[loops];
        loops++;
    }
    do {
        swap = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizefull - 1; i++)
        {
            if (result[i] > result[i + 1])
            {
                tmp = result[i + 1];
                result[i + 1] = result[i];
                result[i] = tmp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);

}


int main()
{
    const int SIZE1 = 3, SIZE2 = 4;
    const int sizefull = SIZE1 + SIZE2;
    int array1[SIZE1] = { 3, 8, 9 };
    int array2[SIZE2] = { -7, -2, 0, 7 };
    int result[sizefull];
    mergeSortedArrays(array1, SIZE1, array2, SIZE2, result);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizefull; i++)
    {
        cout << result[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Click [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5mWG.png) to see what the program displays. I was just wondering if there may be any problem with the "mergeSortedArrays" function at the top, possibly at the part where I insert the values into the "result" array. Thanks to everyone for helping or just lending a hand. :)

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of a buffer overrun. In `result[loops] = array2[loops]`, `loops` goes all the way to `sizefull`, but `array2` doesn't have that many elements. On the flip side, `array2[0]` is never accessed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just noticed that the elements couldn't be accessed.

Comment: Please: next time don't post pictures of text instead of posting the text.

Answer (score 1):

The code has a problem within the "mergeSortedArrays" function.

Your second loop (`while` in `mergeSortedArrays`):

```
while (loops < sizefull)
{
    result[loops] = array2[loops];
    loops++;
}
```

uses wrong indexes for `array2`, i.e. `array2` has only `size2` items, but you use counter `oops` that can be up to `sizefull - 1`.

My suggestion is to add one more counter like:

```
int cnt = 0;
while (loops < sizefull)
{
    result[loops] = array2[cnt++];
    loops++;
}
```

Or use `for` instead:

```
for (int cnt = 0; loops < sizefull; cnt++)
{
    result[loops] = array2[cnt];
    loops++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I apologize for the learner's mistake. I did not notice that.

Comment: Everything will come with experience. By the way, such errors can easily be detected with the help of a debugger